# Updating Array from AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have an array of objects called `audioBaby`.

When the app launches I check `asyncStorage` and if any key has value `active`, I want to update the `lock` keys in the array.

What I have done is not updating all objects in array but only the last object.

How can I `initially` update the array from `asyncStorage` and render the screen?

```
const [audioBaby, setAudioBaby] = useState([
  {
    lock: "deactive",
    url: "item0.mp3",
  },
  {
    lock: "deactive",
    url: "item1.mp3",
  },
  {
    lock: "deactive",
    url: "item2.mp3",
  },
]);

useEffect(() => {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet([
      "babyAudio0Status", //value: active
      "babyAudio1Status", //value: active
      "babyAudio2Status", //value: active
    ]).then((response) => {
      let updatedList = audioBaby;
      if (response[0][1] != "null" && response[0][1] == "active") {
        updatedList = audioBaby.map((item) => {
          if (item.url == "item0.mp3") {
            return { ...item, lock: "active" };
          }
          return item;
        });
      }
      if (response[1][1] != "null" && response[1][1] == "active") {
        updatedList = audioBaby.map((item) => {
          if (item.url == "item1.mp3") {
            return { ...item, lock: "active" };
          }
          return item;
        });
      }
      if (response[2][1] != "null" && response[2][1] == "active") {
        updatedList = audioBaby.map((item) => {
          if (item.url == "item2.mp3") {
            return { ...item, lock: "active" };
          }
          return item;
        });
      }
      setAudioBaby(updatedList)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error::", error);
  }
}, []);
```

Final array should be like this:

```
[
    {
      lock: "active",
      url: "item0.mp3",
    },
    {
      lock: "active",
      url: "item1.mp3",
    },
    {
      lock: "active",
      url: "item2.mp3",
    },
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what `response` looks like after your `multiGet`.  Also, unrelated, you should be using `===` not `==` and `!==` not `!=` unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem and fixed the equalities as what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I moved all `if`s to inside of `map` function and everything is fine.

```
  let updatedList = audioBaby.map((item) => {
          if (item.url === 'item0.mp3' && response[0][1] === 'active') {
            return { ...item, lock: 'active' }
          }
          if (item.url === 'item1.mp3' && response[1][1] === 'active') {
            return { ...item, lock: 'active' }
          }
          if (item.url === 'item2.mp3' && response[2][1] === 'active') {
            return { ...item, lock: 'active' }
          }
          return item
        })
```